# regular expression to match one or more of char a or just one of char b

Tags: java, regex, perl, matching

I am taking user input through UI, and I have to validate it. Input text should obey the following ondition

> It should either end with one or more
>   white space characters OR with just
>   single '='

I can use

> ".*[\s=]+"

but it matches multiple '=' also which I don't want to. 
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin string

Anything not "=" ( to avoid the double "==")

One or more blank spaces **OR** one "="

End of string

```
^([^=]*[\s+|=])$
```

Should work :-)

Comment: simple explanation, works the way I wanted. Thanks @guidhouse

Answer (score 3):

You can use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
(\s+|=)$
```

This expression means *match one or more whitespace character **or** one equals, at the end of the string*. The `$` is an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) which matches the end of the string (as you mentioned you're looking for characters at the end of the string).

(As tchrist correctly pointed out in the comments, `$` matches the end of **line** instead of [end of **string**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#az) when in multiline mode. If this is true in your case, and you are indeed looking for the end of the string instead of the end of the line, you can use `\Z` instead, which matches the end of the string regardless of multiline mode.)

---

If you want to ensure that there is only one `=` at the end, you can use a [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (in this case, a negative lookbehind, specifically). A lookaround is a *zero-width assertion* which tells the regex engine that the assertion must pass for the pattern to match, but it does not consume any characters.

```
(\s+|(?<!=)=)$
```

In this case, `(?<!=)` tells the regex engine, *the character before the current position cannot be an `=`*. When put into the expression, `(?<!=)=` means that the `=` will only match if the previous character is not also a `=`.

Comment: this doesn't check for just one '='. It matches for string ending with two == also

Comment: No, you are mistaken. ① `\s` **does not lose its special meaning in a character class.** ② The \ character is not a slash, but a backslash. ③ If you are using Java, `\s` doesn’t work on Unicode.  Perl, in contrast, supports Unicode. ④ `$` matches both the end of the string and one prior to a newline at the end of a string — or anywhere in multiline mode.

Comment: I think tchrist is right. I can't confirm the claim in Perl or Java.

Comment: @tchrist, @musiKk you're both right. I updated my answer to remove that misinformation.

Comment: I’m rather concerned that the `\s` will match the newline at the end of a non-`chomp` ed string.  Careful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression:

```
".*(\\s+|=)"
```

Comment: How bizarre!  You want the doublequotes to eat your backslash??